# Android webview div OnClick not working in Android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

in my app we are using div onclick to call JavascriptInterface it is working fine up to version 4.3 but in 4.4 it is not working we replaced onclick to ontouch then it works fine
but i dont want to work on ontouch.I want it for only onclick.

this is working code for 4.3

```
<div class=\"newspaper"+hh+"\" id=\"newspaper"+hh+"\" onClick=\"android.pop('omg its working!','newspaper"+hh+"')\" style=\"margin:7px; background:#fdcc76;/>
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: 4.4 switches out the old webview in favor of Chromium. It might have a  new API that you would have to do feature detection for.

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I'm facing the same issue here, `onclick` is not recognized anymore and the only way to detect click events is to use `ontouchend`or similar but it's harder to differentiate from swipes, pinches, double-taps and so on

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the changes made in android 4.4

The webkit's version of `WebView` was replaced with that of `Chromium` one and hence there are changes the way `WebView`s behave in Android 4.4. [This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) might help you migrate your app using `WebView` to 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and onclick is still working in 4.4:

http://jsbin.com/EwEjIyaY/7/edit

So my only assumption is that your html is not valid when you add hh or you might be missing a quote mark on the end of style):

```
style=\"margin:7px; background:#fdcc76;/>
```

to:

```
style=\"margin:7px; background:#fdcc76;\" />
```

If you check what is happening in your WebView with DevTools it should be able to tell you more:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews